# How to handle initializing and rendering subviews in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have three different ways to initialize and render a view and its subviews, and each one of them has different problems. I'm curious to know if there is a better way that solves all of the problems:

---

### Scenario One:

Initialize the children in the parent's initialize function. This way, not everything gets stuck in render so that there is less blocking on rendering.

```
initialize : function () {

    //parent init stuff

    this.child = new Child();
},

render : function () {

    this.$el.html(this.template());

    this.child.render().appendTo(this.$('.container-placeholder');
}
```

The problems:

- The biggest problem is that calling render on the parent for a second time will remove all of the childs event bindings. (This is because of how jQuery's `$.html()` works.) This could be mitigated by calling `this.child.delegateEvents().render().appendTo(this.$el);` instead, but then the first, and the most often case, you're doing more work unnecessarily.
- By appending the children, you force the render function to have knowledge of the parents DOM structure so that you get the ordering you want. Which means changing a template might require updating a view's render function.

---

### Scenario Two:

Initialize the children in the parent's `initialize()` still, but instead of appending, use `setElement().delegateEvents()` to set the child to an element in the parents template.

```
initialize : function () {

    //parent init stuff

    this.child = new Child();
},

render : function () {

    this.$el.html(this.template());

    this.child.setElement(this.$('.placeholder-element')).delegateEvents().render();
}
```

Problems:

- This makes the `delegateEvents()` necessary now, which is a slight negative over it only being necessary on subsequent calls in the first scenario.

---

### Scenario Three:

Initialize the children in the parent's `render()` method instead.

```
initialize : function () {

    //parent init stuff
},

render : function () {

    this.$el.html(this.template());

    this.child = new Child();

    this.child.appendTo($.('.container-placeholder').render();
}
```

Problems:

- This means that the render function now has to be tied down with all of the initialization logic as well.
- If I edit the state of one of the child views, and then call render on the parent, a completely new child will be made and all of its current state will be lost. Which also seems like it could get dicey for memory leaks.

---

Really curious to get your guys' take on this. Which scenario would you use? or is there a fourth magical one that solves all of these problems?

Have you ever kept track of a rendered state for a View? Say a `renderedBefore` flag? Seems really janky.

Comment: i'm usually not sotring references to child views on parent views cause most of the communication happens through models/collections and events triggered by changes to these. Though 3rd case is closest to what I'm using most of the time. Case 1 where it makes sense. Also most of the time you shouldn't be rerendering the whole view but rather the part that have changed

Comment: Sure, I definitely render only the changed parts when possible, but even then I think the render function should be available and non-destructive anyways.

How do you handle not having a reference to the children in the parent?

Comment: Usually i listen to events on the models associated to the child views - if I want to do something more custom then I'm binding events to subviews. If this kind of 'communication' is required then i'm usually creating helper method for creating subviews which binds the events etc.

Comment: For a higher-level, related discussion, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077185/backbone-js-should-nested-views-maintain-references-to-each-other/10941976#10941976 .

Comment: In Scenario Two, why is it necessary to call `delegateEvents()` after the `setElement()`? As per docs: "...and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one", the `setElement` method itself should handle events re-delegation.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

This is a great question. Backbone is great because of the lack of assumptions it makes, but it does mean you have to (decide how to) implement things like this yourself. After looking through my own stuff, I find that I (kind of) use a mix of scenario 1 and scenario 2. I don't think a 4th magical scenario exists because, simply enough, everything you do in scenario 1 & 2 must be done.

I think it'd be easiest to explain how I like to handle it with an example. Say I have this simple page broken into the specified views:

[image: Page Breakdown]

Say the HTML is, after being rendered, something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="name">Person: Kevin Peel</div>
    <div id="info">
        First name: <span class="first_name">Kevin</span><br />
        Last name: <span class="last_name">Peel</span><br />
    </div>
    <div>Phone Numbers:</div>
    <div id="phone_numbers">
        <div>#1: 123-456-7890</div>
        <div>#2: 456-789-0123</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully it's pretty obvious how the HTML matches up with the diagram.

The `ParentView` holds 2 child views, `InfoView` and `PhoneListView` as well as a few extra divs, one of which, `#name`, needs to be set at some point.  `PhoneListView` holds child views of its own, an array of `PhoneView` entries.

So on to your actual question.  I handle initialization and rendering differently based on the view type.  I break my views into two types, `Parent` views and `Child` views.

The difference between them is simple, `Parent` views hold child views while `Child` views do not. So in my example, `ParentView` and `PhoneListView` are `Parent` views, while `InfoView` and the `PhoneView` entries are `Child` views.

Like I mentioned before, the biggest difference between these two categories is when they're allowed to render. In a perfect world, I want `Parent` views to only ever render once. It is up to their child views to handle any re-rendering when the model(s) change. `Child` views, on the other hand, I allow to re-render anytime they need since they don't have any other views relying upon them.

In a little more detail, for `Parent` views I like my `initialize` functions to do a few things:

1. Initialize my own view
2. Render my own view
3. Create and initialize any child views.
4. Assign each child view an element within my view (e.g. the `InfoView` would be assigned `#info`).

Step 1 is pretty self explanatory.

Step 2, the rendering, is done so that any elements the child views rely on already exist before I try to assign them. By doing this, I know all child `events` will be correctly set, and I can re-render their blocks as many times as I want without worrying about having to re-delegate anything. I do not actually `render` any child views here, I allow them to do that within their own `initialization`.

Steps 3 and 4 are actually handled at the same time as I pass `el` in while creating the child view. I like to pass an element in here as I feel the parent should determine where in its own view the child is allowed to put its content.

For rendering, I try to keep it pretty simple for `Parent` views. I want the `render` function to do nothing more than render the parent view. No event delegation, no rendering of child views, nothing. Just a simple render.

Sometimes this doesn't always work though. For instance in my example above, the `#name` element will need to be updated any time the name within the model changes. However, this block is part of the `ParentView` template and not handled by a dedicated `Child` view, so I work around that. I will create some sort of `subRender` function that *only* replaces the content of the `#name` element, and not have to trash the whole `#parent` element. This may seem like a hack, but I've really found it works better than having to worry about re-rendering the whole DOM and reattaching elements and such. If I really wanted to make it clean, I'd create a new `Child` view (similar to the `InfoView`) that would handle the `#name` block.

Now for `Child` views, the `initialization` is pretty similar to `Parent` views, just without the creation of any further `Child` views.  So:

1. Initialize my view
2. Setup binds listening for any changes to the model I care about
3. Render my view

`Child` view rendering is also very simple, just render and set the content of my `el`.  Again, no messing with delegation or anything like that.

Here is some example code of what my `ParentView` may look like:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#parent",
    initialize: function() {
        // Step 1, (init) I want to know anytime the name changes
        this.model.bind("change:first_name", this.subRender, this);
        this.model.bind("change:last_name", this.subRender, this);

        // Step 2, render my own view
        this.render();

        // Step 3/4, create the children and assign elements
        this.infoView = new InfoView({el: "#info", model: this.model});
        this.phoneListView = new PhoneListView({el: "#phone_numbers", model: this.model});
    },
    render: function() {
        // Render my template
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        // Render the name
        this.subRender();
    },
    subRender: function() {
        // Set our name block and only our name block
        $("#name").html("Person: " + this.model.first_name + " " + this.model.last_name);
    }
});
```

You can see my implementation of `subRender` here. By having changes bound to `subRender` instead of `render`, I don't have to worry about blasting away and rebuilding the whole block.

Here's example code for the `InfoView` block:

```
var InfoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // I want to re-render on changes
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);

        // Render
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        // Just render my template
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    }
});
```

The binds are the important part here.  By binding to my model, I never have to worry about manually calling `render` myself.  If the model changes, this block will re-render itself without affecting any other views.

The `PhoneListView` will be similar to the `ParentView`, you'll just need a little more logic in both your `initialization` and `render` functions to handle collections. How you handle the collection is really up to you, but you'll at least need to be listening to the collection events and deciding how you want to render (append/remove, or just re-render the whole block). I personally like to append new views and remove old ones, not re-render the whole view.

The `PhoneView` will be almost identical to the `InfoView`, only listening to the model changes it cares about.

Hopefully this has helped a little, please let me know if anything is confusing or not detailed enough.

Comment: Really thorough explanation thanks. Question though, I've heard and tend to agree that calling `render` inside the `initialize` method is a bad practice, because it prevents you from being more performant in cases where you don't want to render right away. What do you think about this?

Comment: Sure. Hmm... I only try to have views initialized that should be shown right now (or could be shown in the near future, e.g. an edit form that's hidden now but shown upon clicking an edit link), so they should be rendered immediately. If say, I have a case where a view takes a while to render, I personally don't create the view itself until it needs to be shown, so no initialization and rendering will take place until necessary. If you have an example I can try to go into more detail about how I handle it...

Comment: It is a big limitation to not be able to re-render a ParentView. I have a situation where I basically have a tab control, where each tab shows a different ParentView. I would like to just re-render the existing ParentView when a tab is clicked a second time, but doing so causes events in the ChildViews being lost (I create children in init, and render them in render). I guess I either 1) hide/show instead of render, 2) delegateEvents in the ChildViews' render, or 3) create children in render, or 4) don't worry about perf. before it is a problem and re-create the ParentView each time. Hmmmm....

Comment: I should say it is a limitation in my case. This solution will work fine if you don't try to re-render the parent :) I don't have a good answer but I have the same question as OP. Still hoping to find the proper 'Backbone' way. At this point, I am thinking hide/show and don't re-render is the way to go for me.

Comment: Now, we can use after/before render functions to seperate logic?

Comment: Thank you for this amazing explanation. Just two questions, wouldn't it be a wiser decision to use Marionette when dealing with subviews? Also how would one go about binding events to the child views in case we pass in a collection from the parent view as well and would want the child view to be re-rendered on a collection reset?

Comment: how do you pass the collection into the child `PhoneListView`?

Comment: @IanStormTaylor @KevinPeel — What about putting `this.trigger( 'render' );` in the parent view's `render`? Then pass the parent view along when creating the child views: `new InfoView({ parent: this, /*...*/ });`. Finally, in the child view's `initialize`: `this.listenTo( arguments.options.parent, 'render', this.render );`.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. It has been so useful to me, thank you. Glad to see it's as popular as it deserves to be! I notice this was written in '12, and is therefore using bind() in the code and not listenTo(). Perhaps worth updating that now?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this directly answers your question, but I think it's relevant:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

The context in which I set up this article is different, of course, but I think the two solutions I offer, along with the pros and cons of each, should get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

To me it does not seem like the worst idea in the world to differentiate between the intital setup and subsequent setups of your views via some sort of flag. To make this clean and easy the flag should be added to your very own View which should extend the Backbone (Base) View.

Same as Derick I am not completely sure if this directly answers your question but I think it might be at least worth mentioning in this context.

> [Also see: Use of an Eventbus in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180796/358114)

Answer (score 4):

Kevin Peel gives a great answer - here's my tl;dr version:

```
initialize : function () {

    //parent init stuff

    this.render(); //ANSWER: RENDER THE PARENT BEFORE INITIALIZING THE CHILD!!

    this.child = new Child();
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to avoid coupling between views like these. There are two ways I usually do:

#### Use a router

Basically, you let your router function initialize parent and child view. So the view has no knowledge of each other, but the router handles it all.

#### Passing the same el to both views

```
this.parent = new Parent({el: $('.container-placeholder')});
this.child = new Child({el: $('.container-placeholder')});
```

Both have knowledge of the same DOM, and you can order them anyway you want.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is giving each children an identity (which Backbone has already done that for you: cid)

When Container does the rendering, using the 'cid' and 'tagName' generate a placeholder for every child, so in template the children has no idea about where it will be put by the Container.

```
<tagName id='cid'></tagName>
```

than you can using

```
Container.render()
Child.render();
this.$('#'+cid).replaceWith(child.$el);
// the rapalceWith in jquery will detach the element 
// from the dom first, so we need re-delegateEvents here
child.delegateEvents();
```

no specified placeholder is needed, and Container only generate the placeholder rather than the children's DOM structure. Cotainer and Children are still generating own DOM elements and only once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a light weight mixin for creating and rendering subviews, which I think addresses all the issues in this thread:

https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.subviews

The approach taken by this plug is create and render subviews after the *first* time the parent view is rendered. Then, on subsequent renders of the parent view, $.detach the subview elements, re-render the parent, then insert the subview elements in the appropriate places and re-render them. This way subviews objects are reused on subsequent renders, and there is no need to re-delegate events.

Note that the case of a collection view (where each model in the collection is represented with one subview) is quite different and merits its own discussion / solution I think. Best general solution I am aware of to that case is the [CollectionView in Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md).

EDIT: For the collection view case, you may also want to check out [this more UI focused implementation](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.collectionView), if you need selection of models based on clicks and / or dragging and dropping for reordering.