# backbone.js uncaught typeError in parentView trying to instantiate a subView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, render

I'm trying to debug this code for a parentView.  The error thrown from this code is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined".  The console.log also comes back as undefined, however if I console.log the same this.model.total_fans later in the render function, it has a value.  I don't know backbone well enough to debug this annoyingly and potentially miniscule error, but I feel like something the way this is setup is wrong, especially after reading posts about dealing with rendering subviews within a masterview here [How to handle initializing and rendering subviews in Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337927/how-to-handle-initializing-and-rendering-subviews-in-backbone-js).  I'm wondering what all is wrong here.  Should I instantiate the subviews within the parents initialize?  And should the parent be calling render and pagesetup on model changes??

```
initialize:function () {
    var self = this;

    // General model for this page
    this.model = new geodemoModel();

    // separate summary model
    this.summaryModel = new summaryModel();

    this.model.fetch();
    this.summaryModel.fetch();

    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    this.model.bind('change', this.pageSetup, this);

    this.summaryModel.bind('change', this.render, this);
    this.summaryModel.bind('change', this.pageSetup, this);

  },

pageSetup:function () {
 if (this.oneSelect == 'All' || this.oneSelect == 'lifetime_fans') {
        console.log(this.model.total_fans);
        var viewLifetime = new lifetimeView(this.model.total_fans.attributes.total_fans_object);
        $('#lifetimeFans').html(viewLifetime.render().el);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model exists, you should be using:

```
this.model.get('total_fans').attributes.total_fans_object
```

if that doesn't work, please paste a `console.log(this.model)` within `pageSetup`.

Comment: child {cid: "c7", attributes: Object, _changing: true, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
_changing: true
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
dates: Object
previous: Object
selected: Object
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c7"
queryParams: Object
top_engagement_by_country_28: child
top_engagement_demographics_28: child
top_fans_by_country_28: child
top_fans_demographics_28: child
top_reach_by_country_28: child
top_reach_demographics_28: child
total_fans: child
total_fans_demo: child