# How to avoid double event binding in Backbonejs View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var RowView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'course-row',
    events: {
        "click .table-row": "rowClick" // problem here!
    },
    initialize: function() {},
    template: _.template(tpl),
    render: function() {

        var rowStr = this.template({course: this.model});
        $(this.el).append(rowStr);
    },
    rowClick: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

Above code defines a Backbone Row view. I'd like to create and render several several rows in a table, so I did:

```
data.forEach(function(rowData){
    var row = new RowView({model: course, el: mountPoint});
    row.render();
});
```

**If I create 2 rows, the event is bind twice( 2 alert msg if I click on the row), 3 rows 3 times.** I avoided this problem by defining the event at parent views, but if I really need attach event handler at each row, how do I avoid the double event biding problem?

Comment: There's some strategies for parent / child views in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9502515/3585500). But also don't miss the [pub/sub answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9415369/3585500) further down.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Can you create a [mcve]..?

Comment: The presence of `tagName` and `className` in your `RowView` suggests that `RowView` creates its own `el`. But in that case, a simple `row.render()` wouldn't get anything on the page. Also, the double events suggest that you're binding multiple views to the same `el`. Those things suggest that that's not your real `forEach` loop. What am I missing?

Comment: @muistooshort I use "new RowView({model: course, el: mountPoint});" to create a view, so when rendering, row will render itself on the page. I just updated my question to address your question. Thanks!

Comment: @TJ: Just the old "I'm using one `el` for multiple views" problem all over again, that explains 90% of the "one event being trigger multiple times" bugs with Backbone.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this:

```
data.forEach(function(rowData){
    var row = new RowView({model: course, el: mountPoint});
    row.render();
});
```

That means that your view will ignore its `tagName` and `className` and just go ahead and bind itself to the `el` you supply [because](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties.

A view's [`events` are bound to its `el` using delegation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) and you're binding multiple views (which happen to be the same view "class") so of course you're getting multiple event bindings.

If your rows really are supposed to be `<li class="course-row">` elements then you want to do a couple things:

1. Let the `RowView`s create and own their own `el`s. Keep the `tagName` and `className` attributes in your `RowView` and stop passing the `el` to the constructor. You should change `$(this.el)` to [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) too, there's no need to create another jQuery object when Backbone has already stashed one away for you.
2. Return `this` from `RowView`'s `render`, this is standard practice and makes the next step a bit nicer.
3. Whatever creates your `RowView`s should create them, `render` them, and then put them inside a container. You appear to be trying to use `mountPoint` (which is presumable a `<ul>`) as the container so you want to say:

   ```
   data.forEach(function(rowData) {
       var row = new RowView({model: course});
       mountPoint.append(row.render().el);
       // This is why (2) above -----^^^
   });
   ```

   That assumes that `mountPoint` is a jQuery instance, if that's not the case then you'd want to say `$(mountPoint).append(row.render().el)` instead (or do a `var $mountPoint = $(mountPoint)` above the `forEach` and use `$mountPoint.append` inside it).

A personal rule of thumb: if you're passing `el` to a view constructor then you're almost certainly making a mistake. If you know exactly why you're passing `el` to the constructor, know the consequences, and know how to deal with them then you're adult enough to run with scissors so go right ahead.