# What is the correct usage for backbonejs view's initialize() and render()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I find the usage of the different elements of backbonejs quite ambiguous. From my undestanding, this was the intention as backbone didn't want to be a framework, but more of a set of tools/objects.

I understand most parts of backbonejs, but i'm still questioning what is the correct usage for a view's initialize() and render() calls. In other words, what logic should be placed within each.

Could someone explain what is best practice or what is considered correct usage of these calls within a view?

Comment: i am pretty sure that you already came across this link, but in any case i had the same problems and solved most of them here, its not exaclty the same topic you are refering too cause its about subviews, but gets you a good idea on how everything works together
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337927/how-to-handle-initializing-and-rendering-subviews-in-backbone-js

Comment: you haven't come across a _correct usage_ because one isn't described, the best anyone could do would be to give you their opinion, but that's not what SO is about. There is a [Backbone primer](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Backbone%2C-The-Primer) linked to from the official docs, and it shows an example with _initialize_ calling _render_, which I personally do not like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty far-ranging question, but I'll give it a try. The key takeway here is that there is no such thing as "*the* correct usage" for these calls. Backbone is flexible on purpose and meant to adapt to your needs. That's why it still has its place in a world of more sophisticated, but "opinionated" frameworks (which tell you that it's "my way or the highway").

Backbone does not use any magic with respect to rendering. The `render()` method is a no-op and not even invoked automatically for you. Its existence is nothing more than a hint how things are usually done.

The `initialize()` method, however, is invoked automatically when the view is instantiated. Backbone guarantees that at that point, the top-level DOM element of the view (the `el`) has already been created and is ready to have stuff attached to it.

But again, that's pretty minimal: the top-level element is there, but not yet attached to the DOM (unless you passed `options.el` to the constructor, setting the `el` to an existing element). Inserting the `el` into the DOM is your job, too.

So you are free to decide how to wire things up. What I typically do is this:

- Most of my views have a template, which is commonly assigned to the `template` property of the view. (Again, just a convention, no magic involved. You could name it `foo`.) That template is compiled in `initialize()`.
- In `initialize()`, I set up the relationship with a model or a collection which the view is supposed to represent. Ie, the view observes model/collection events and is made to call `render` when the data has changed. (You don't have to use a Backbone entity as your data source, of course ... could be anything).
- In `render()`, the data is fed into the template, and the result becomes the innerHTML of the `el`. Afterwards, I make sure the `el` is inserted into the DOM if it isn't already.
- The first call to `render()` should happen when the data is ready. The right moment depends on the app. Perhaps `render()` is the last call in `initialize()`, or some event will kick it off later on.

If a lot of that sounds like repetitive boilerplate to you, yes, that's exactly what it is. Frameworks like [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs) exist on top of Backbone to take care of that.

But there is a sigificant performance penalty for that framework magic. So when I have to generate a lot of views, I stick to the generic Backbone stuff (and use one of my [own](https://github.com/hashchange/backbone.declarative.views) [components](https://github.com/hashchange/backbone.inline.template) for speeding up the template handling.)